# Submodules links not showing in GitLab repo GUI

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I have added some git submodules oninmy project. Everything is working ok in VSCode, I can see the submodules and manage everything from the root project.

On gitlab.com though, I cannot see the submodules references in the repository, but I do remember it was working like this in other projects I have.

My current `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "project_1"]
    path = lib/project_1
    url = git@gitlab.com:company/sdk/packages/project-1.git

[submodule "project_2"]
    path = lib/project_2
    url = git@gitlab.com:company/sdk/packages/project-2.git
```

I should be seeing something similar to this (from another project):

[image: GitLab GUI Submodules]

But I do not see anything. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Have you used `git push` to send the commits from your Git repository on your local machine to the other Git repository on your GitLab setup?

Comment: @torek yes all the repo are pushed and full of code

Comment: Perhaps it's just a delay in the display from the web interface, then. I don't know the detailed inner workings of GitLab (or Bitbucket or GitHub for that matter), but any time you have a huge cluster of many machines that simulate a single machine, you get cases where database updates lag real-time—a sort of "eventual consistency" model—or very slow or unavailable systems. This is the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) (or Brewer's theorem).

Comment: I don't think so. It's been three days already